# Azure Functions - NumPy MemoryError in building a large vector over 800MB

Tags: python, function, azure, numpy, memory

My python code in Azure Function creates a large matrix over 1024*1024*100 with a float64 numpy datatype (8bytes/per entry) which results in obtaining 838860800 bytes (800MB) by, for example:

```
a = np.arange((1024*10)**2, dtype=np.float64)
```

The server throws an 'MemoryError' exception from NumPy like:

`2017-09-18T20:43:43.812 Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerPython3. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Traceback (most recent call last):`

and the function failed. I assume that Consumption Plan automatically scales the required memory upto 1536MB from 128MB for applications but I do not think it was properly applied to my python code. How do I make sure enough resources are allocated to my function? Is this because of using the HTTP trigger and the Python runtime instead of using the Queue trigger and C#? I suspect that Scale Controller decides the amount of resource allocated to a function and manages scalability based on the stacked queue length and wait time but I am not sure how to complete my function without out of resources. I wish I can define a minimum memory requirement in the configuration as an advanced mode. BTW, I was able to create a matrix of 1024*1024*81 which consumes 648MB.

Comment: What was your Python code doing on Azure Functions? I'm not sure whether Azure Function is suitable with your scenario.

Comment: It's for matrix multiplication. One of my other python code is also to read data files (approx. 500+ MB) from object storage i.e. blob storage for a simple computation and it may consume most memories allocated to containers but under 1536MB. Either of them won't succeed unless I particularly reduce the amount of memory required i.e. 600~800MB based on my experience. I understand CPU and memory intensive jobs may work better on dedicated nodes rather than serverless frameworks but I am trying to see if there are some type of applications compatible with Functions (performance and cost wise).

Comment: Just per my experience, I think Azure Batch Service or Azure VM for Compute/Memory Optimized is better and more suitable with your scenario, although their cost are higher. You can refer to the offical pricing pages to know them [Azure Batch](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/batch/) and [Azure Linux VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/).

Comment: I'll try Azure Batch. My stateless code completes its tasks within a few minutes or less so the fast launching and millisecond charge of Functions seemed better to me when I started working on this. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: You are welcome!